# How to manually resize a Pane/Rectangle in JavaFX with a mouse drag?

Tags: java, javafx, resize, components, pane

I have a standard JavaFX Pane object that I want the user to be able to stretch or compress from any of the four sides. Only problem is I'm not so sure how to go about it.

I already have code that resizes the Pane and the TextArea object within it to a specified width/height, but I want to add a MouseEvent or ActionEvent listener to the edges of the pane to allow for resizing from the user. The current listener that I have for the Pane object allows the user to drag it around the screen (which is what I desire), but dragging the entire thing isn't the problem; I also need to be able to resize it.

```
mainPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED,
  new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle( MouseEvent event )
    {
       event.setDragDetect( true );
       dragDetected();
       event.consume();
    }
```

I should also mention that I have a JavaFX Rectangle object which serves as the backbone for the Pane and its respective TextArea. If I need to post more code, please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: I should probably mention that the only thing that is being resized in my code is the Rectangle and TextArea; NOT the Pane itself.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926063/javafx-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-set-aspect-ratio/48931614#48931614) may be similar.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..